# How to deploy aws infrastructure in multiple regions using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to deploy my infrastructure to multiple regions, right now I am doing this using provider-alias and thus a single state file is created.

```
main.tf


module "mumbai" {
  source                    = "./site-to-site-vpn-setup"
  providers                 = { aws = aws.mumbai }
  vpc_cidr                  = local.vpc_cidr
  cg_ip_address             = lookup(local.region_map, "mumbai", "") == "" ? "" : lookup(local.region_map, "mumbai", "").cg_ip_address
}

module "seoul" {
  source                    = "./site-to-site-vpn-setup"
  providers                 = { aws = aws.seoul }
  vpc_cidr                  = local.vpc_cidr
  cg_ip_address             = lookup(local.region_map, "seoul", "") == "" ? "" : lookup(local.region_map, "seoul", "").cg_ip_address
}

providers.tf


provider "aws" {
  alias  = "mumbai"
  region = "ap-south-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "seoul"
  region = "ap-northeast-2"
}
```

Now, for example I want to increase the computes for all the regions but I want to first apply it to say 2 regions for testing. With the current structure if I do terraform apply then it is applied in all the regions. Now one solution can be to create different directories for different regions and thus different state files for each, Now how can this be optimized further or what other better approaches are there?

Comment: I don't know if it is a better way but you could send the value you want to differ in the different regions to the module with a var when you call it. Like you have done with vpc_cidr. But doing this in this way you have to state that value for all uses of that module.

Comment: yes it is fine for now, but when we scale up, it will not be a good solution.

Comment: You could also have a bool value you send in to the module. And then have a if function getting either the test value or the standard value. In this way you only have to change the value in one place.

Comment: Why would it be applied to all regions? You are specifying one provider per module, so you would then only modify it for one module mapped to one provider alias mapped to one region.